# Azure Website - Web API Swallowing Errors

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api

I have a asp.net web api application deployed as an azure web app. One of the endpoints occasionally throws an exception. Normally this isn't an issue for us. We have an `ExceptionLogger` attached to the api services. This has been in place for sometime and normally works fine.

Currently we see that a 500 response comes back from the server, but nothing is logged. I have tried setting `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy` to `IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always`, but the response always comes back with no body content.

What else can I do to track the source of the problem?

Comment: have you tried the Failed Request Tracing: http://bit.ly/1eMMAU6 and also attaching application insights to the api: http://bit.ly/1NjXDPa you can also attach your visual studio directly: http://bit.ly/1dlWBGg

Answer (score 0):

If you have a consistent repro, then you can use remote debugging to attach to your web app and debug it (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio/).

Failing that, you can enable better diagnostic logs using the web app settings. Information on how to do so is here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/ under the section "Enabling diagnostic logs".
 In your case you should have application logging enabled, and perhaps failed request tracing would be useful (FREB).

For even more tools you can use the Support Site Extension (http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/12/01/new-updates-to-support-site-extension-for-azure-websites/) which would allow you to look at live event logs and HTTP traffic. For a deeper dive into debugging in Azure App Service see: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Ignite/2015/BRK4704.